# Replace parts of a paragraph

Tags: perl, openoffice.org, cpan

I'm currently trying to insert a paragraph into an Open Office Writer document from a perl script, then search through that paragraph for a particular phrase, and replace it with another, using `setTextSpan()`. I can insert the paragraph easily, just when it comes to applying the style, nothing seems to work. Example code extract is as follows:

```
my $doc = odfDocument(
    container => $container,
    part      => 'content',
);

$place = $doc->selectElementByContent("LOCATION");

$doc->insertParagraph(
    $place,
    position => 'before',
    text => "Sample text for demonstration purposes"
);

doc->setTextSpan(
    $place, 
    replace => "Sample text",
    text => "replaced Text"
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind mentioning what kind of object `$doc` is?

Comment: Sure thing, added it to the code now.

Comment: Hmm. And where is `odfDocument` implemented?

Comment: How do you mean by implemented?

Comment: What module are you using to write your open office documents? It's really, really hard to guess from here.

Comment: @innaM `odfDocument()` is a convenience function to create an `OpenOffice::OODoc::Document`. @DaveMoore Maybe you pass-in the wrong `$place` to the `setTextSpan()` method? Does the insertParagraph() method return the inserted element?

Comment: Woooooah, chill the f*ck out! This is part of someone else's massive Perl Module that I'm trying to edit with little to no Perl experience whatsoever. Looking at the declarations, the module being used is `OpenOffice::OODoc`